# DELIVERY_PSV_PRICE is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

Я не кодер. От слова совсем. Помогает чатgpt в мелочах но. Столкнулся с проблемой сначала не отображались пункты выдачи на карте. Нашел у соседей так сказать загрузил файл их загрузил картинки нужные к файлу, пункты начали отображаться корректно но все также не кликабельны.
[image: Карта]

При нажатии на любой пункт, вылазит ошибка в F12

[image: Скриншот Developer console]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ищите в коде эту переменную - она не определена.